# How to install a deb file, by dpkg -i or by apt?

Tags: software-installation, apt, dpkg, deb

I have a deb package for installation.

Shall I install by `dpkg -i my.deb`, or by apt?

Will both handle the software dependency problem well?

If by apt, how can I install from the deb by apt?

Comment: You could use `aptitude` which removes unnecessary packages as well.

Comment: I recommend not to directly use `dpkg`. In case of single deb, go with [**gdebi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#GDEBI) and in case of multiple debs, go for [APT local repository](https://sites.google.com/site/debianpackagemanagement/setting-local-repository).

Comment: why ......... @Pandya

Comment: @Tim because `dpkg` doesn't resolve dependencies.

Comment: @Tim gdebi identifies missing dependencies, can download & install (using apt),can install &  configure (using dpkg).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/196864/how-to-install-local-deb-packages-with-apt-get

Answer (score 1545, accepted):

When you use `apt` to install a package, [under the hood](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianPackageManagement) it uses `dpkg`. When you install a package using apt, it first creates a list of all the dependencies and downloads it from the repository.

Once the download is finished it calls `dpkg` to install all those files, satisfying all the dependencies.

#### So if you have a `.deb` file, you can install it by:

1. Using:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
2. Using:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./name.deb
   ```

   Or

   ```
   sudo apt install /path/to/package/name.deb
   ```

   With old `apt-get` versions you must first move your deb file to
   `/var/cache/apt/archives/` directory. For both, after executing this command, it will automatically download its dependencies.
3. First installing `gdebi` and then opening your .deb file using it (*Right-click* -> *Open with*). It will install your .deb package with all its dependencies.

**Note**: APT maintains the package index which is a database (`/var/cache/apt/*.bin`) of available packages available in repo defined in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. All these methods will fail to satisfy the software dependency if the dependencies required by the deb is not present in the package index.

---

#### Why use `sudo apt-get install -f` after `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file`  (as mentioned in method 1)?

From `man apt-get`:

```
 -f, --fix-broken
           Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
```

When `dpkg` installs a package and a package dependency is not satisfied, it leaves the package in an "unconfigured" state and that package is considered broken.

The `sudo apt-get install -f` command tries to fix this broken package by installing the missing dependency.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make "the .deb package present in the apt package list"?

Comment: Sorry @Tim, I didn't understand what you are asking. Pls add bit more detail in your comment.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/620056/install-a-package-moved-to-var-cache-apt-archives-manually/620059#comment876271_620059

Comment: @Tim, apt-get is designed to install packages from repository. It maintains packages list as well as their respective repository address. So just moving a .dev file, which is not present in the apt package list, in /var/cache/apt/archives directory will not work. Because whenever you try to install this package using apt-get, it searches for its repository, which is not present.  For this you have to create local repository which I think is useless.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer - "You can install it using sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file followed by sudo apt-get install -f" --> is this with two separate commands, or is it all on the same line? I was a litttle confused.

Comment: @g_p thank you! im a little confused in your answer above. you write: "(it will work if the .deb package is present in the apt package list)" - I do not understand what is meant here. How can one ensure that the .deb package is present in the apt package list?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon, I have added bit information in my answer. To find-out if a package is present in the index or not run `apt-cache search <package name>`. You can also use `apt-cache policy <package name>`, which will give some additional information as well.

Comment: Well, nowadays, you can right click and open the .deb file with Ubuntu Software Center too. That installs it for you. Dunno about the advantages and disadvantages of doing this though.

Comment: Will these methods still perform the signature checking usually performed by apt? Or is it possible for a tampered-with .deb file to be installed this way?

Comment: I'd like to point out as well for gamers in here that this is how you install discord.

Comment: Why `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file` is followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`?

Comment: @Tim,updated the answer.

Comment: Modern apt-get can be uset to install a package simply with `apt-get install /path/to/package/name.deb`.  It would be neat if the author of this answer decided to integrate that.  If not, I'll go add that answer sometime when I have enough rep here

Comment: Anyone able to get the /var/cache/apt/archives/ method to work. I like it however it doesn't work for me when I move the deb in update and then try to install the package.

Comment: @mschuett please post your query as new question and give the relevant information.

Comment: Thanks for adding the comment about what `apt-get install -f` does. Thorough answer!

Comment: I come to this answer once a month. For some reason I can not remember this ... :\

Comment: I came to this again because I got `Unable to locate package`. I used as in Windows just name of package after switching to `archive` folder. Forgot `./` for Unix...

Comment: FYI, the ability to run `apt install foo.deb` was added in [apt 1.1](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/e02297b8e22dae04872fe6fab6dba966de65dbba/debian/changelog#L2410).

Comment: Doesn't work for me:
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
dpkg: warning: downgrading libstdc++6:amd64 from 8.2.0-1ubuntu2~18.04 to 8-20180414-1ubuntu2
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'linux-modules-4.15.0-1027-aws' is missing final newline


sudo apt install libstdc++6_8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb 

apt: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: invalid ELF header

Comment: Everyone above is writing `/path/to/package/name.deb` . But what is that path? How to find it?

Comment: @AgentZebra if you download the `.deb` to your `~/Downloads` folder, just `cd ~/Downloads` then the path is just "." (here); e.g, `sudo apt install ./install-me.deb` , or if you prefer, `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/install-me.deb`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f /path/to/.deb`  worked for me

Comment: 1. worked for me to install teamviewer on Ubuntu 16.04. Appreciate it

Comment: You might need to use `sudo dpkg --force-depends -i /path/to/package.deb`

Comment: The `sudo apt install ./foo.deb
` way I always get _Note, selecting 'on_repo_foo' instead of './foo.deb'_. `dpkg -i` seems the only way to force the installation of the .deb.

Comment: "Note: APT maintains the package index which is a database of available packages"   
Where dir. is it ?

Comment: @cantiknonokmu `/var/cache/apt/*.bin`

Comment: On modern distros you can also use apt-get install ./package.rpm. The key thing is to use an absolute path, or start it with a ./

Comment: When trying `sudo apt install ./package.deb` on my Ubuntu 22.04, I get an error as follows (the original german and my translation into english)  
`N: Der Download wird als root und nicht Sandbox-geschützt durchgeführt, da auf die Datei »/home/user/Downloads/package.deb« durch den Benutzer »_apt« nicht zugegriffen werden kann. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Keine Berechtigung)`  
`N: The download is conducted as root and is not Sandbox-protected, since the file »/home/user/Downloads/package.deb« can not be opened by the user »_apt«. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: no permission)`

Comment: @DohnJoe please check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403337/download-is-performed-unsandboxed-as-root-as-file

Answer (score 127):

Install your `foo.deb` file with `dpkg -i foo.deb`. If there are some errors with unresolved dependencies, run `apt-get install -f` afterwards.

Comment: I got `Unable to locate package` trying this way and got puzzled. I used as in Windows just name of package after switching to archive folder. Should be `./<file name>` for Unix if in current folder or full path. That is if `deb` is not in folder present in `PATH`.

Comment: For scripting, use `apt update && dpkg -i foo.deb || apt install -f -y` to make sure that `foo.deb` is not removed by `apt install -y`.

Comment: `sudo` is needed for `dpkg` and `apt` or `apt-get`.

Answer (score 110):

You can install a local .deb package by:

```
sudo apt install ./foo.deb
```

Make sure to specify a local relative or absolute path (`./` if in current dir), otherwise it will look for `foo.deb` in the remote repos and fail.

Answer (score 81):

Here's the best way to install a `.deb` file on Ubuntu on the command-line:

```
sudo gdebi skype.deb
```

If you don't have `gdebi` installed already, install it using `sudo apt install gdebi-core`.

## Why gdebi?

`gdebi` will look for all the dependencies of the `.deb` file, and will install them before attempting to install the `.deb` file. I find this much preferable than `sudo dpkg -i skype.deb && sudo apt install -f`. The latter is much too eager to remove dependencies in certain situations. For instance, when I tried to install Skype, it attempted to remove 96 (!) packages, including packages like `compiz` and `unity`! `gdebi` gave a much clearer error message:

```
 $ sudo gdebi skype.deb
 Cannot install 'libqtgui:i386'
```

(Here is [the solution to that particular issue](https://askubuntu.com/a/553283/2355), by the way.)

Comment: worked great thx! btw, could be that the attempt to remove were about that transitional/temporary packages? or you think it would really break the system?

Comment: Dude I ran into an issue with your solution. I was trying to install Rstudio. It automatically found an old version of R for me. While using the solution by @g_p I was able to install Rstudio only.

Answer (score 14):

Check the dependencies with `dpkg -I my.deb` and `apt-get install` the dependencies before `dpkg -i my.deb`.

<s>May be you can copy the `my.deb` in `/var/cache/apt/archives` and install it directly with `apt-get` but I never tried.</s>
Doesn't work, `apt-get` and `dpkg` are looking for packages listed in archives.

Comment: Thanks. in your first sentenct, do you mean `apt-get install my.deb` by `apt-get install`? Is it to install from the deb file? Why do we need `dpkg -i my.deb` after that?

Comment: I always installed local `.deb`s with `dpkg -i`, my understanding is that `apt` doesn't have an option to install them, apart the directory in `/var/cache/...` where are downloaded (I may be wrong)

Comment: It seems that `apt-get install ./my.deb` will do something, because it outputs a lot of things. What does it do?

Comment: It does too much :-) doesn't work, see @Igor_Dvoretskyi answer is just perfect, I forgot about `-f`

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer would be to use dpkg by running `dpkg -i packagename.deb`. You could then uninstall it by running `dpkg -r packagename.deb`.

`apt-get` is a higher level installer based off of dpkg, and as such you could `apt-get install packagename.deb`.

It would be beneficial for add it to your apt-get archives directory (`/var/cache/apt/archives`) so you could reference it as a package with dependencies and not a standalone .deb archive.

Also, by adding it to your apt-get archives directory, you have the opportunity to use dependencies with `apt-get install packagename`. This would let you install it with any manually added dependencies instead of dpkg's standalone archive-based system.

Comment: Note: if you want to use `apt-get install` with a local package file, you must install it in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, otherwise `apt-get` may decide to download it anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Modern apt-get can be used to install a package simply with `apt-get install /path/to/package/name.deb`.

(should be done as edit to the top answer but it was rejected - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/159114/edit)

Comment: This did not work with `apt 1.0.9.8.4 for amd64 compiled on Dec 11 2016 09:48:19`

Answer (score 2):

The shortest way to install a local package with all required dependencies that worked for me:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install ./name.deb
```

It is `--fix-broken` option that makes dependencies to be installed.

Answer (score -4):

It is very simple if I want to install Chrome.

Install your Chrome file as:

```
dpkg -i googlechrome.deb.
```

Sometimes there is a chance of getting some dependency errors like the following:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
google-chrome-stable depends on libappindicator1; however:
Package libappindicator1 is not installed.
```

So to resolve above issues, you need to add dependencies; give the following command:

```
apt-get install -f
```

After giving the above command, dependencies will be added to your machine and your Debian package (`.deb`) file will be installed.