# Package deb dependency problem

Tags: debian, ubuntu, openssl, debian-installer, cmake

I am using `CMake` for my application named `Agent`. After configuring and generating binaryfiles, the application was compiled using the `make` command and `Agent.exe` was created in the build directory.Then I executed the application from terminal using `./Agent` command. It worked.

Then I had created `Debian package` for the application using `CPack` and `efsagent.deb` was created. But while trying to install the package using the command `dpkg -i efsagent.deb`, it fails with following error:

```
`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of efsagent:
efsagent depends on libssl (>= 0.9.8); however:Package libssl is not installed.`
```

But `libssl` is already installed in my system and `libssl.so.0.9.8` is in `/usr/local/ssl/lib` path..

How can I link the dependencies to the generated package??

Comment: see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159103/120177

Answer (score 3):

If you really have to have that local obsolete OpenSSL 0.9.x - not something anyone could recommend given the security implications - use `equivs` to generate a dummy `libssl` package that will indicate its existence in the packaging system. But you should really just use the normal system OpenSSL packages to build your applications, that is, build after installing `libssl-dev`, and depend on the system OpenSSL library package such as `libssl1.0.0`.

Comment: I did not think that problem is related to OpenSSL version ..Because the it works from the build directory  with OpenSSL 0.9.8.

Comment: The manually built library as such is the immediate problem. The later consequences are an additional problem