# debian jessie 8.2 manually install wpasupplicant and dependencies

Tags: debian, wpa-supplicant

I have to manually install wpa_supplicant in order to connect to my router and get internet connection

The only chance that I have at the moment is to manually download the files in my usb stick from another PC, then mount the stick in debian and put the files in the proper directories (manually installing them)

I downloaded wpasupplicant [.deb](http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_2.3-1+deb8u3_amd64.deb) the from [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/wpasupplicant/download)
and imported the files from the usb stick using `mkdir`, `mount` and `umount`

Then I run `dpkg -i` followed by `apt-get install -f` as described in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/146143)

But seems that there are unresolved subdependecies and at one point the installation interrupted by an "insert cd rom" prompt

---

Output of:

**`# lsb_release -a`**:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release:    8.2
Codename:   jessie
```

**`# uname -a`**:

```
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u3 (2015-08-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Software components in Debian are installed using .deb files.

[deb (file format)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29)

Using search in [Debian Search package directories](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages)

The package you need is wpasupplicant and the jessie page for it is [Package: wpasupplicant (2.3-1+deb8u3) [security]](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/wpasupplicant)

From uname we know you have an amd64 system, so a possible URL for it linked by that page is as of today:

[wpasupplicant package from main update](http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/w/wpa/wpasupplicant_2.3-1+deb8u3_amd64.deb)

After downloading the wpasupplicant*deb file in another PC, bringing it over with a pen, and mounting it, you can install it using dpkg with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i wpasupplicant*amd64.deb
```

Dependencies (from /var/lib/dpkg/status)

`Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libnl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libnl-route-3-200 (>= 3.2.7), libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.1), lsb-base`

Some of them are probably installed.

Using again https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_packages

http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.19-18+deb8u1_amd64.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-3-200_3.2.24-2_amd64.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.24-2_amd64.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libn/libnl3/libnl-route-3-200_3.2.24-2_amd64.deb
http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1k-3+deb8u2_amd64.deb
http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/l/lsb/lsb-base_4.1+Debian13+nmu1_all.deb

This may bring some other dependencies, which you can find again in the search page.

Nonetheless, if in another working Debian amd64 system, instead of downloading one by one, you can download a package and it´s dependencies:

[How to download all dependencies and packages to directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756800/how-to-download-all-dependencies-and-packages-to-directory)

```
sudo aptitude clean
sudo aptitude --download-only install <your_package_here>
sudo cp /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb <your_directory_here>
```

**Note:** If this doesn't work with your actual version of Debian, try do this instead:

```
sudo cd /somedirectory
sudo apt-get download PACKAGE && apt-cache depends -i PACKAGE | awk '{print $2}' | xargs  apt-get download
```

As for the sources.list file, comment for now the line that starts with "deb cdrom:" in /etc/apt/sources.list

I then recommend that after you have Internet connectivity, you put your sources.list as follows:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

And run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Please can you post only the missing ones? And how I have to temporarily set the source.list file to complete the installation avoiding it asking me the cd rom?

Comment: I added a few more details.

Comment: I do not know exactly which ones you have. I can guess that you certainly already have libc6 and lsb-base . You can check the list of packages installed with `dpkg -l`

Comment: opening this page with lynx or if in another debian amd64, following the tip to downloading the package and the dependencies in one go

Comment: after I run: `aptitude --download-only install wpasupplicant` the cache folder is still empty. If I run it again, or I run `apt-get -d install wpasupplicant` it says that it is already up to date, but where?? If I check the files including invisibles inside the cache folder running `ls -a /var/cache/apt/archives` this is the output:
`.  ..  lock  partial`

Comment: finally I was able to only download all dependencies into a specified directory, after moved inside with cd, like described here http://superuser.com/a/876735/306947 Now I will import and install them, and I will tell you what happens

Comment: I just installed them using `dpkg -i *.deb` no errors this time (I not even touched the source.list file for cd rom prompt). Now I will try to reboot and see if I can use wpasupplicant

Comment: I need to install wireless-tools, I will do it now

Comment: good news then! How did it go?

Comment: I installed wireless-tools, but I still cannot use `iwconfig`.... I also tried to run: `/sbin/iwconfig` but the command is still not found

Comment: does `dpkg -l wireless-tools`shows something?

Comment: dpkg-query: no packages found matching wireless-tools

Comment: If is not in the list, it was not installed...any error?

Comment: Now I will google another bit, maybe I am missing something at this point, I  am loosing some enthusiasm

Comment: It would not be the first time I would copy the installation DVD to an USB pen an install from there. Maybe it would be easier for you, while you are getting your feet wet.