# Why can't sudo apt install locate a deb file?

Tags: apt, sudo

```
$ ls
wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb

$ sudo apt install wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb'
```

I was wondering why the `deb` file can't be located?

Is it because of `sudo` or `apt install`?

Thanks.

Note that

```
$ sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb
```

works, but I was asking for the reason of the previous failure.

Related [How to install a deb file, by dpkg -i or by apt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt)

Comment: Try specifying the absolute path to the `.deb` file perhaps?  Also, I wonder if the tildes in the filename are potentially causing issues.  I have often used `sudo apt install package.deb`, so I know that in general it _will_ work as you appear to expect.

Comment: Off-topic, but ``sudo dpkg -i package_name.deb`` is probably the answer to how many people will view this question.  Also off-topic, using dpkg is vastly faster because it won't do dependency checking, and also works on distros that don't even have apt installed.  Hope many of you find that helpful.

Comment: `dpkg` not doing dependency checking is _why_ I prefer to use `apt` to install one-off packages.

Answer (score 23):

Since version 1.1~exp1, `apt` and `apt-get` support installing from package files accessible *via* the file system, and not just from repositories. However, in order to preserve backwards compatibility, the feature only works for package specifiers which are *unmistakably* files, *i.e.* which contain `/`. Anything else is processed as a package *name* rather than a package *file*, using the pre-existing mechanisms.

Thus

```
sudo apt install wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb
```

is handled as a request to install the package named “wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb”, and `apt` goes looking for that in its repositories and fails.

But

```
sudo apt install ./wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb
```

is handled as a request to install the package contained in the file named “./wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb” (along with its dependencies, if necessary). This also works for absolute paths.

I can’t find any trace of this in the `apt` documentation though, apart from the brief mention in [the changelog](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/blob/15df82d2c8a29ac179ddcd57eb849d3ad0f2561f/debian/changelog#L2290):

> - add support for "apt-get install foo_1.0_all.deb"

There is [a bug requesting that this feature be documented](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=874763).

Answer (score -3):

The command `apt install` doesn't install `.deb` files. To install the deb file `wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb`, use `dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-0.20180604.140.rc~6f77c46~bionic_amd64.deb`. `dpkg -i` is used to install `.deb` files.

Comment: `dpkg -i` can be used to install `.deb` packages, but so can `apt install`; I do it routinely when updating Plex Media server with `sudo apt install ./packagefile.deb`.

Comment: From the `apt` changelog, 1.1~exp1: *add support for "apt-get install foo_1.0_all.deb"*