# Installation of debian file

Tags: debian

I have a set of `dll` files and I converted those into zip file and made it as `.deb` file, now I want to install this file in ubuntu. How to install this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install a deb file, by dpkg -i or by apt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt)

Answer (score 5):

You can install a local `.deb` file to your system via:

```
dpkg -i yourfile.deb
```

- Please note that while debs files are compressed, they are not
  necessarily zip archives. Also, the archive contents must follow
  strict rules as described in the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html).
- Please also note that dll files are made for use on Windows and not
  for Linux. I hope you know what you are doing.