# "apt install ./file.deb" vs "apt install /path/to/file.deb"

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, filenames, deb

I was looking to install a .deb file and found an answer here: [How to install a deb file, by dpkg -i or by apt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt)

I just want to know the difference between using:

`sudo apt install ./name.deb`

and

`sudo apt install /path/to/package/name.deb`

Why isn't the second option:

`sudo apt install ./path/to/package/name.deb`

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two variants look for the package in different locations (unless the current directory is the root directory).

```
sudo apt install ./path/to/package/name.deb
```

looks for a package file named `name.deb`, in the subdirectories `path`, `to`, `package`, starting from *the current directory* (`.`). This only works if the current directory contains a directory named `path`, which itself contains a directory named `to`, which itself contains a directory named `package`, which contains the file `name.deb`.

```
sudo apt install /path/to/package/name.deb
```

looks for a package in the directory `/path/to/package`, *i.e.* the same sequence as above, but starting from the root directory, not the current directory.

Put another way, `./` isn’t part of the `apt` syntax, it’s part of the file’s path, and interpreted as usual for paths.