# Wifi Adapter not Found on X1 Carbon 3rd Gen

Tags: debian, wifi, thinkpad, firmware, iwlwifi

I recently installed Debian onto my 3rd gen Thinkpad X1 Carbon and am having some issues with getting WiFi to work. I tried following quite a few different suggestions online and none seem to be helping me - here is some info about my machine and what I have done already. Bluetooth works perfectly.

Output of `nmcli device`:

```
DEVICE  TYPE     STATE       CONNECTION
enp0s25 ethernet unavailable --
lo      loopback unmanaged   --
```

And the response of `lspci` doesn't have a wireless controller inside. Ethernet Controller is `Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 3)`.

Output of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` is nothing.

I can't run modinfo because it isn't installed.

My computer has an Intel 7265 Wireless card, and I've tried downloading both the drivers from here - [List of firmware in Linux kernel](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware#List_of_firmware_in_Linux_kernel) and dropping them into `/lib/firmware`, which didn't work for me. Nothing appeared to change.

I tried following this guide - [Re: wifi not working on my new lenovo thinkpad x-1](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=219442#p1150475) but it requires installing software onto my laptop without internet, which I can't easily do. Keryx doesn't appear to be working anymore, and I can't install software with its dependencies onto my X1 Carbon effectively over bluetooth.

Any advice or suggestions?

Comment: The common way is to install the [firmware-iwlwifi](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-iwlwifi) package from the non-free repository. See [wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi).

Comment: I am not able to install software with dependencies easily. I can drop the files onto the computer via bluetooth but outside of that I can't install software onto the machine. Any advice on how I could do that?

Comment: Can you download the package from [http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-iwlwifi_20190114-2_all.deb](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-iwlwifi_20190114-2_all.deb) (assuming you're running buster) and install it [manually](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114/332764)?

Comment: Yes! I just installed the package onto my machine and restarted, internet works now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you please write a short answer and accept it later? Thank you!

Comment: Sure! Freddy, I have another question for you - now that the firmware for this wireless adapter is installed, if I installed a different distro (like Arch or Fedora) would internet work out of the box or would I have to go through a similar process again? How would I install this without apt?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would guess other distros come with the firmware out-of-the-box. For Debian I tend to use the [non-free](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/) ISO images for installations, because I'm too lazy to use an ethernet cable to install missing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download and install the firmware for your device's wireless adapter. [If your device uses an Intel WLAN adapter, follow this guide.](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi)
2. If your device isn't connected to the internet, the iwlwifi firmware can be installed without an internet connection:

   1. Download the iwlwifi firmware from [here](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-iwlwifi_20190114-2_all.deb).
   2. Move the .deb file to your device.
   3. Install the file:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /path/to/deb/file
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

4. Restart your machine. Internet should now work!