# How to install locally stored ".deb" packages?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I am working in an air-gapped environment where there is no internet.

I would like to install certain packages that are in my home directory. These packages are put here through USB device. Now, I have 50 `.deb` files in my home directory. And I would like to install them using `sudo apt install`.

Can help me on how can I make the `sudo apt install` command recognize this path?

I am new to Ubuntu. So, can anyone provide step by step info please?

Comment: have you try with `dpkg` command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a deb file, by dpkg -i or by apt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159094/how-to-install-a-deb-file-by-dpkg-i-or-by-apt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use different paths:

via `apt` - `sudo apt install /path/to/package`

or via `dpkg` - `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package`

If you want to install all packages in directory you can use something like:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/packages/*
```

Comment: Tjanks, upvoted. Will this pick the dependencies as well? If they are in the same folder?

Comment: @TheGreat, check my edited answer

Comment: I would like to install all 50 packages which contains their dependancies as well. Currently I wrote single sudo apt install command but it failed due to dependency. But all my dependencies are in the folder as well. How can I make the command recpgnize the dependencies and install approproately?

Comment: @TheGreat, the last command in my answer should do the work

Answer (score 2):

another way if all packages (with depencecies are in one folder)

```
sudo apt-get -o dir::cache::archives="Path/to/folder/with/debs" install what ever.
```

Only tested from me with apt-get not with apt.